# Development log also recorded while running in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

While running RAILS 3 application in production mode , the development log also gets recorded along with production log.It should only give the production log right?

Answer (score 0):

You might have started another rails server in development mode :P

Answer (score 0):

How do you do? Which server? Do you use this code?

> rails s -e production